# Problema com formulario + ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Fiz uma requisição ajax para enviar os dados de um formulário para o servidor, os dados são enviados e armazenados perfeitamente. Porém ao tratar o **success**
criando a condição, caso o retorno do **result** fosse o padrão **200** ou **"OK"** iria emitir uma mensagem de sucesso e se não, a de erro. Porém, ao fazer isso percebi que o result não estava retornando pois já caia direto no else. E mesmo caindo ELSE, ele armazena os dados no servidor, porém lança a mensagem de erro.

```
function sendForm()
{

  $("#divSucesso").hide();
  $("#divError").hide();

  document.getElementById("btnEnviarForm").disabled = true;
  // var formAgenda = document.getElementById("form");
  var formData = new FormData (document.forms[0]);

  $.ajax({
      url: 'insert.php',
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      dataType: 'html',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,

      success: function (result) {

          if (result.substring(0, 2) == "OK")
          {
            document.getElementById('divSucesso').innerHTML = "Dados salvos com sucesso: " + result;
            $("#divSucesso").stop().fadeIn(200).delay(50000).fadeOut(200);
            document.getElementById("form").reset();
          }
          else
            showMessageError(result);

          document.getElementById("btnEnviarForm").disabled = false;            
        },

      error: function (xhr, status, error) {

      showMessageError(status + error + xhr.responseText);
      document.getElementById("btnEnviarForm").disabled = false;
    }

  });

}

  function showMessageError(message)
  {
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = message;
    $("#divError").fadeIn(200).delay(2500).fadeOut(200);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Ajax do jQuery, o `success:` já significa que o código *status* do XHR de retorno foi `200`. É redundante fazer uma verificação de `OK` (que seria o `xhr.statusText` no terceiro parâmetro do retorno) dentro do callback, já que ele sempre será "OK" no `success:`:

```
success: function (result, status, xhr){

   // result -> dados HTML de retorno
   // status -> retorna a string "success"
   // xhr    -> objeto XHR gerado

}
```

Para pegar os códigos do retorno `200` e `OK`:

```
success: function (result, status, xhr){

   xhr.status; // retorna "200"
   xhr.statusText; // retorna "OK"

}
```

Comment: Não funcionou. O que fiz foi por o result em um alert e ver o retorno, o mesmo são os dados coletados do formulário. sabe me dizer o por que disso ?

Comment: resposta padrão que seria quando ocorre td OK ao levar dados pro servidor. OK ou 200 caso fosse o certo, e 404 ia ser de erro. Mas o pega está ai, ele armazena no banco de dados mas o resultado não é OK ou nem 200, ele esta pegando os dados que é inserido no formulário.

Comment: Não é assim não, vc está confundindo as coisas. No Ajax do jQuery, o success: significa que tudo deu certo e o retorno é o HTML da página requisitada. Usando XHR em JS puro é que vc verifica o status da requisição.

Comment: ah sim, entendi.

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta. Dá pra pegar o "OK", mas seria redundante pq o success já significa que deu tudo OK.

Comment: É que eu preciso tratar um erro, pois quando não ocorre um sucesso ele aparece a mensagem dizendo que foi sucesso.

Comment: Dá uma olhada agora.